# Do we allow to have a tag named after a particular place?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am preparing for two Expeditions in Himalays, one of them is simpler, late this year, and the other which is probably a tough one in the next year around August. Regarding both the places I seek some personal opinions and Guidelines, and past experience if any.
For that I was wondering if we can have a tag for Himalays and some other great outdoor exped locations. Can we? Or else I may have to ask every question with the name specified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think **yes**.  Outdoor questions by their very nature can be localised, just like travel questions.  Therefore, place-based tags make a lot of sense.

Comment: However, I would only use location-based tags **when the location is *central* to the question.** Someone asking how to sharpen a machete shouldn't tag the question [brazil] because they happen to mention it's for a trip the Amazon.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Well, yes of course.  A Swedish outdoor forum I frequent gets dozens of questions per day, half of them are of the style "is river X fordable at location Y in autumn" or "does route A through valley B encounter a lot of dense vegetation" or "what's the snow situation in location L like right now" — all good questions but localised in space and sometimes time too.

Comment: Tags are cheap!